# seprate cookies for different user roles in Node + Express + Passport

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, passport-local

I had made a project in `express` framework of nodejs, which uses passport local strategy for authentication along with `cookie-parser`, `express-session`, I set user-id to the cookie and de-serialize it and retrieve user data from `mongoDb` using the id set in cookie each time a route is called. Now i want to add a new user role to the project so i added usertype attribute to each user type but the issue is i am not able to login simultaneously to both user role i.e customer & admin in a single browser because only one cookie is set either it can store customer id or admin id

how can i set separate cookies each for different user role, i am not asking for any code just a suggestion on library or package will be enough.

Comment: you wouldn't set that in the cookie - you set in the user object

Comment: so you saying i need to set two different objects to same cookie for each user role ? ...Hmmm... looks like i have asked something very silly.....anyway i am fairly new to node and express..!! Let me work on that

Comment: no, when you set the user object in the passport `deserializeUser`, you can pass anything you want in there, and then you can access it in `req.user`, for instance `req.user.isAdmin` .. or `req.user.usertype` in your case

Comment: ok i get it , just one last thing , there is no use or possibility for making two different local strategy of passport for each user role, coz that's what was striking in my mind.

Comment: that doesn't make sense to me

Comment: what do you think will be best way to deal with a situation where admin, customers both can login from same browser & same computer., the way suggested by you in second comment will do it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164707/discussion-between-paqash-and-gaurav-kumar).